# `date_to_string` in a different language?

Tags: xml, jekyll

I'm new to Jekyll and I'm currently starting a blog written in Spanish. I want to convert an XML time schema to a string in Spanish. Ex, instead of "Updated 01 Jan.  2017", I want "Actualizado el 01 de enero de 2017" or something similar. Is there a way to convert `date_to_string` into something that would fit my needs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there's nothing in Jekyll that can do this out-of-the-box. You'll have to write a bit of code to get the name of the months, etc. in your language.

Here is an example:

```
<!-- Whitespace added for readability -->
{% assign m = page.date | date: "%-m" %}
{{ page.date | date: "%-d" }}
{% case m %}
  {% when '1' %}Januar
  {% when '2' %}Februar
  {% when '3' %}M&auml;rz
  {% when '4' %}April
  {% when '5' %}Mai
  {% when '6' %}Juni
  {% when '7' %}Juli
  {% when '8' %}August
  {% when '9' %}September
  {% when '10' %}Oktober
  {% when '11' %}November
  {% when '12' %}Dezember
{% endcase %}
{{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}
```

You can see a number of other examples on date formatting with Jekyll here:
http://alanwsmith.com/jekyll-liquid-date-formatting-examples

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't ask for multiple languages, I thought it would be good to add that here. Below is how I add multiple languages to blog posts, etc.

_includes/date.html:

```
{% capture hide %}

{% if include.mode != 'month' %}

  {% assign day = include.date | date: "%-d" %}

{% endif %}

{% if page.language == 'th' %}

  {% assign m = include.date | date: "%-m" %}
  {% case m %}
    {% when '1' %}
      {% capture month %}มกราคม{% endcapture %}
    {% when '2' %}
      {% capture month %}กุมภาพันธ์{% endcapture %}
    {% when '3' %}
      {% capture month %}มีนาคม{% endcapture %}
    {% when '4' %}
      {% capture month %}เมษายน{% endcapture %}
    {% when '5' %}
      {% capture month %}พฤษภาคม{% endcapture %}
    {% when '6' %}
      {% capture month %}มิถุนายน{% endcapture %}
    {% when '7' %}
      {% capture month %}กรกฎาคม{% endcapture %}
    {% when '8' %}
      {% capture month %}สิงหาคม{% endcapture %}
    {% when '9' %}
      {% capture month %}กันยายน{% endcapture %}
    {% when '10' %}
      {% capture month %}ตุลาคม{% endcapture %}
    {% when '11' %}
      {% capture month %}พฤศจิกายน{% endcapture %}
    {% when '12' %}
      {% capture month %}ธันวาคม{% endcapture %}
  {% endcase %}

{% else %}

  {% capture month %}{{ include.date | date: "%B" }}{% endcapture %}

{% endif %}

{% capture year %}{{ include.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}

{% endcapture %}
```

_includes/post-time.html:

```
{% include date.html date=post.date %}

<time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}">{% if page.language == 'th' %}{{ day }} {{ month }} {{ year }}{% else %}{{ month }} {{ day }}, {{ year }}{% endif %}</time>
```

Then I can use `{% include post-time.html %}` wherever I need the above HTML output.

You could also add an extra conditional to the `_includes/date.html` file if you wanted three languages.